# Что неправильно в коде jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var lenght = ($('#inner-scroll1 > div').lenght) * 252;
            $('#inner-scroll1').width(lenght);
});
```

Надо вычислить общую ширину внутренних div (один div имеет ширину 252px) внутри #inner-scroll1 и присвоить её собственно #inner-scroll1

Comment: может разметку еще дадите ? и jsfiddle ?

Comment: но вообще

* lenght пишется length;
* свойство length это длина массивоподобной коллекции и переводится как длина
* `($('#inner-scroll1 > div').lenght) * 252;` непонятно что вы хотели этим добиться.

Comment: Спасибо, всё дело в опечатке.

Всё правильно, мне нужно было вычислить вложенных дивов и умножить их на известную ширину отдельного - 252. В результате получаю общую ширину, которую и присваиваю внешнему элементу

Comment: @eicto чего тут непонятного? количество элементов DIV умноженных на 252 - вычисляется ширина элемента $('#inner-scroll1') в зависимости от количества других элементов, видимо какой-то костылик

Answer (score 1):

опечатка в свойстве length

```
$('#inner-scroll1 > div').lenght  > $('#inner-scroll1 > div').length
```